# Twitter api reply to tweet

Tags: node.js, twitter

I'm trying to write a script to reply to a tweet, using the `twit` npm module. However whenever I pass the `in_reply_to_status_id_str` or `in_reply_to_status_id` this seems to be ignored. Not sure what the issue is?

```
   T.get('search/tweets', { q: `golf since:2011-07-11`, count: 1 }).then(function (response) {

            const userName = response.data.statuses[0].user.screen_name;
            const tweetId = response.data.statuses[0].id_str;

            T.post('statuses/update', { in_reply_to_status_id_str: tweetId, status: `@${userName}, I like golf too` }, (err, data, response) => {
              resolve()
            })
          })

        })
```

Answer (score 6):

You should be passing the param as `in_reply_to_status_id` instead of `in_reply_to_status_id_str`.

```js
T.get('search/tweets', { q: `golf since:2011-07-11`, count: 1 }).then(function (response) {

            const userName = response.data.statuses[0].user.screen_name;
            const tweetId = response.data.statuses[0].id_str;

            T.post('statuses/update', { in_reply_to_status_id: tweetId, status: `@${userName}, I like golf too` }, (err, data, response) => {
              resolve()
            })
          })

        })
```